Powershell function which communicates over TCP to a Zebra printer
I have a Powershell function that communicates over TCP to a Zebra printer:
function Out-ZebraPrinter {
    param(
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string]$Command,
        [string]$IpAddress
    )
    try {

        [System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient]$client = [System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient]::new()
        $client.SendTimeout = 1000 # milliseconds (1 second)
        $client.ReceiveTimeout = 500 # milliseconds (0.5 second)
        $client.Connect($IpAddress, 9100)
    
        [System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream]$stream = $client.GetStream()
        $writer = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($stream)
        $reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($stream)

        # [System.IO.StreamWriter]$writer = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($client.GetStream())
        # [System.IO.StreamReader]$reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($client.GetStream())
    
        # send ZPL
        $writer.Write($Command)
        $writer.Flush()
    
        # read response
        $Response = $null
        [char[]]$buffer = [char[]]::new(1024)
    
        do
        {
            try {
                $size = $reader.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length) # <-- hangs when ReceiveTimeout is 0 and no additional data is present
                $Response += -join $buffer[0..($size - 1)]
            }
            catch [System.IO.IOException] {
                break
            }
        } while ( $size -gt 0 )
    
        $Response ? $Response.Trim() : $null
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "FATAL: $( $_.Exception.Message )" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
    finally {
        $reader.Close()
        $reader.Dispose()
    
        $writer.Close()
        $writer.Dispose()
    
        $client.Close()
        $client.Dispose()
    }

}

Invoke it (get host status):
$Status = '~HS' | Out-ZebraPrinter -IpAddress '192.168.1.209'

# <STX> = \x02 - 2
# <ETX> = \x03 - 3
# <CR> = \x0D - 13
# <LF> = \x0A - 10

# <STX>030,0,0,0414,000,0,0,0,000,0,0,0<ETX><CR><LF>
# <STX>001,0,0,0,1,2,6,0,00000000,1,000<ETX><CR><LF>
# <STX>0000,0<ETX>

$Commands = ($Status -replace '[\x02\x03\x0D]', '') -split '\x0A'
$Commands

Can the code be improved, particularly the StreamReader part.
$Response = $reader.ReadToEnd() generates an exception:

Unable to read data from the transport connection: Operation timed out.

